# getParent() when an fxml is loaded in a container

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Here is my main page controller to load `home.fxml` in `borderPane` center:

**MainController.java**

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

@FXML   private BorderPane borderPane;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    try {
        Connection connection = SqlConnection.dbConnector();

        //JDBC connection initial check
        if (connection != null) {
            newLoginStage();
            connection.close();
        }
        goToHome();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//ToolBar Methods
@FXML   public void goToHome() throws Exception {
    toolBarButtonClick(homeTB, "home.fxml");
}
@FXML   private void logout() throws Exception {
    Stage stage = (Stage) borderPane.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.hide();
    newLoginStage();
    stage.show();
}
@FXML   public void exit() throws Exception {
}

private void toolBarButtonClick(Button button, String fxml) throws Exception {
    button.setDisable(true);
}
private void newMainContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxml));
    borderPane.setCenter(fxmlLoader.load());
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    mainContent = new MainContent(borderPane);
    BorderPane parentBorderPane = (BorderPane)borderPane.getParent();
    parentBorderPane.setLeft(null);
}
```

I was planning to hide the left part of the `borderPane` from the main page, but I can't get the parent with `borderPane.getParent()` in `HomeController.java`.

Comment: Can't you just set `borderPane.setLeft(null);` in `newMainContent(String fxml)` method in MainController, after loading `home.fxml`?

Comment: The `initialize()` method in a controller is called during the ``FXMLLoader.load()` process - i.e. it is called before `load()` exits. So the root node of the FXML cannot possibly have been added to a parent at that point, and consequently `getParent()` will return null. As @MBec suggests, it's not really the responsibility of a "child" controller to update the contents of whatever node contains its UI; that should be done by your main controller.